# After fresh install of Visual Studio 2017, project throws System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I just reset my computer, installed Visual Studio 2017, and pulled up a C# WPF project that used to work before I reset my machine (in 2017 RC) and works right now on other machines.  This project references a dll called Eagle.Core.  I fired it up in Debug and I got a `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` when calling an extension method (ObservableCollection.ObservableWhere([lamda])) in Eagle.Core:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException occurred
>     HResult=0x80070002
>     Message=Could not load file or assembly 'System.Reactive.Linq, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=94bc3704cddfc263' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>     Source=Eagle.Core
>     StackTrace:
>      at Eagle.Core.Utilities.PclWeakEventManager`3.AddHandler(TEventSource source, TEventHandler handler, Func`2 converter, Action`1 add, Action`1 remove)
>      at Eagle.Core.Collections.ObservableQueriedCollection`2..ctor(ICollection`1 source, IEnumerable`1 initItems, LambdaExpression expression)
>      at Eagle.Core.Collections.ObservableFilteredCollection`1..ctor(ICollection`1 source, Expression`1 filterExpression)
>      at ObservableCollectionExtensions.ObservableWhere[T](ICollection`1 source, Expression`1 filterExpression)
>      at TestWpf2017.MainWindow..ctor() in C:\Builds\Personal\Projects\TestWpf2017\TestWpf2017\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 34

Just to be sure, I created a new WPF project and referenced Eagle.Core and called the same method, and sure enough, the problem arose again.

**Any suggestions?**

---

### More info

---

I assume it is something with my Visual Studio installation.  I had some troubles first installing it, and I had installed the core of Visual Studio (No workloads selected) and then modified it to add the other things I needed.

After this problem arose, I repaired Visual Studio.  I hope I do not have to do an uninstall and reinstall.  I doubt even that will help.  :(

Here is what is installed (found in Help > About Microsoft Visual Studio):

> Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 Version 15.0.26228.4 D15RTWSVC
>   Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.6.01586
>
> Installed Version: Enterprise
>
> Visual Basic 2017   00369-60000-00001-AA352 Microsoft Visual Basic
>   2017
>
> Visual C# 2017   00369-60000-00001-AA352 Microsoft Visual C# 2017
>
> Visual C++ 2017   00369-60000-00001-AA352 Microsoft Visual C++ 2017
>
> Visual F# 4.1   00369-60000-00001-AA352 Microsoft Visual F# 4.1
>
> Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package   8.6.00209.10
>   Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio
>
> ASP.NET and Web Tools 2017   15.0.30223.0 ASP.NET and Web Tools 2017
>
> ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2017   5.2.50127.0 For additional
>   information, visit https://www.asp.net/
>
> Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   15.0.30209.0 Azure App Service Tools
>   v3.0.0
>
> Common Azure Tools   1.9 Provides common services for use by Azure
>   Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.
>
> JavaScript Language Service   2.0 JavaScript Language Service
>
> JavaScript Project System   2.0 JavaScript Project System
>
> JavaScript UWP Project System   2.0 JavaScript UWP Project System
>
> KofePackagePackage Extension   1.0 KofePackagePackage Visual Studio
>   Extension Detailed Info
>
> Merq   1.1.13-alpha (2f64b6d) Command Bus, Event Stream and Async
>   Manager for Visual Studio extensions.
>
> Microsoft MI-Based Debugger   1.0 Provides support for connecting
>   Visual Studio to MI compatible debuggers
>
> Microsoft Visual Studio VC Package   1.0 Microsoft Visual Studio VC
>   Package
>
> Mono Debugging for Visual Studio   Mono.Debugging.VisualStudio Support
>   for debugging Mono processes with Visual Studio.
>
> NuGet Package Manager   4.0.0 NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio.
>   For more information about NuGet, visit http://docs.nuget.org/.
>
> SQL Server Data Tools   15.1.61702.140 Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools
>
> StylerPackage Extension   1.0 StylerPackage Visual Stuido Extension
>   Detailed Info
>
> TFS Auto Shelve   6.0 Create a shelveset for the latest version of all
>   pending changes, automatically.  Pending changes from the local TFS
>   workspaces will be shelved to the TFS Server every "x" number of
>   minutes when solutions are opened.
>
> TypeScript   2.1.5.0 TypeScript tools for Visual Studio
>
> Visual Studio Tools for Universal Windows Apps   15.0.26228.00 The
>   Visual Studio Tools for Universal Windows apps allow you to build a
>   single universal app experience that can reach every device running
>   Windows 10: phone, tablet, PC, and more. It includes the Microsoft
>   Windows 10 Software Development Kit.
>
> Xamarin   4.3.0.784 (73f58d6) Visual Studio extension to enable
>   development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.
>
> Xamarin.Android SDK   7.1.0.41 (9578cdc) Xamarin.Android Reference
>   Assemblies and MSBuild support.
>
> Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   10.4.0.123 (35d1ccd) Xamarin.iOS and
>   Xamarin.Mac Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.

Comment: Install the correct version of this nuget package in the project https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reactive.Linq/

Comment: That worked.  

The problem is, it works without the nuget on other machines.  I should not have to do this.  What other things will I run into?  Why did this just start happening?

Comment: I bet the file System.Reactive.Linq.dll is present on all of these computers. Maybe installed through nuget in Visual Studio or installed with some other software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As NineBerry stated as a comment under my question, install the correct version of this nuget package in the project nuget.org/packages/System.Reactive.Linq

Comment: You're able to take his comment and make it your answer. Comments are temporary by nature. Plus bonus rep for having a proper answer.

Comment: @TankorSmash how?

Comment: Just by editing your answer, and explain what his comment was and how you fixed it. Basically make your answer the standalone answer to your question.